# If the matrix $A$ is perturbed by a symmetric matrix $E$, then its eigenvalues do not move by more the $||E||$

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, singular-values

"Matrix Computations" by Golub and Van Loan, 4th ed, Chapter 2, Corollary 2.4.4 says:

If $A\in R^{m\times n} and E\in R^{m\times n}$, then 
$$\sigma_{min} (A+E)\geq \sigma_{min}(A)-||E||_2$$
$\sigma$ are singular values.

The proof says the results above follow from
$$\sigma_{min}(A)\cdot ||x||_2\leq||Ax||_2 \leq\sigma_{max}(A)\cdot ||x||_2.$$

I tried the following:
$$\sigma_{min}(A)||x||_2\leq||Ax||_2\leq||A||_2||x||_2$$ for some $x$ s.t. $||x||_2=1$, so 
$$\sigma_{min}(A)\leq||A||_2\leq||(A+E)||_2+||E||_2.$$

But it does not seem to work well.

---

Edit1: sorry I mistyped the sign in the equation I was intended to prove.

Comment: You mean singular values?

Comment: Something doesn't look right, take $A=0$ in the first equation, this gives $\underline{\sigma}(E) \le - \|E\|_2$ which is true **iff** $E = 0$.

Comment: I think this question requires Weyl's inequality of perturbed matrices.

Comment: The first relation sign should be turned around. And symmetric matrices are usually square.

Comment: If you mean eigenvalues: $((A+E)x,x) + \|E\| = (Ax,x) + (Ex,x) + \|E\|\ge (Ax,x)$. Now apply the infimum over $\|x\|=1$. It's that simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sigma_{min}(A+E)=\min_{\|x\|_2=1}\|Ax+Ex\|_2\leq \min_{\|x\|_2=1}\|Ax\|_2+\max_{\|x\|_2=1}\|Ex\|_2=\sigma_{min}(A)+\|E\|_2.$$

The inequality follows by setting $x$ to be a value minimizing $\|Ax\|_2$ subject to $\|x\|_2=1.$

Comment: Why does that inequality hold?

Comment: @angryavian: explanation added

Comment: How does this show Corollary 2.4.4? Isn't it supposed to be $\sigma_{\min}(A + E) \ge \sigma_{\min}(A) - \lVert e \rVert_2$?